# Opengl add a new object in each click?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

```
void onClick(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
  if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    drawHouse(x,y);
}
```

I have a problem about opengl onclick function. I drawed an object(primitive house) and i want to display it when i click on the mouse. How can i do this?

My teacher gave this command: "**Add a new object, defined in the first part, after the user presses mouse left button. Each click adds a new object at the position of click. Maximum 10 objects can be created on the screen. Then, after each click a new object should replace the first object.**"

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no i stuck in there...

Comment: @Rabbid76 good idea, but can you give me a code example?

Comment: @hsntrk What have you tried so far? Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's your homework and Stackoverflow is no code writing service.

Comment: @Rabbid76 calm down man, i just asked a little help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible soultion would be to store the mouse positions in an array with length of 10. Each click adds a new entry to the array. If the array is full, the entries get overwritten:

```
#define MAX_OBJ 10

int pos_x[MAX_OBJ], pos_y[MAX_OBJ];
int count  = 0;
int next_i = 0;

void onClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
       pos_x[next_i] = x;
       pos_y[next_i] = y;
       next_i ++;
       if ( next_i == MAX_OBJ ) next_i = 0;
       if ( count < MAX_OBJ )   count ++;
    }
}
```

In the main loop you can draw the objects to the known positions:

```
for( int i = 0; i < MAX_OBJ; ++ i )
    drawHouse( pos_x[i], pos_y[i] );
```